# Shares created via WSHNetwork.MapNetworkDrive are not visible by administrator

Tags: windows-7, administrator, vbscript

I have a script that maps some network drives via `WSHNetwork.MapNetworkDrive` - but those drives are not visible by processes running as `Administrator`.

Is there any solution to it? (maybe some flag?)

Running on `Windows 7`